# Simplifing PHP or statements

Tags: php

Okay, I believe that I can simplify this line of code except I can't find anything online. Can anyone help me?

```
if(empty($action) || $action == "a" || $action == "b" || $action == "c") {
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: To be grammatically correct, shouldn't your name be "anhonorstudent"?

Comment: @TheBigO - Maybe the name is supposed to be ironic? +1 for LOLs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to search an array of possible values for `$action`:

```
if (empty($action) || in_array($action, array('a', 'b', 'c'))) {
}
```

I keep the `empty()` condition separate because `empty()` tests true for a number of things besides the empty string `''`.

If all you care is to test for the empty string, you can include it in `in_array()`, and get rid of that `empty()`:

```
if (in_array($action, array('', 'a', 'b', 'c'))) {
}
```

Performantly, I think explicitly including `empty()` is a teeny weeny little bit better, due to [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Thank you. I never knew you could use arrays for `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$options = array("a", "b", "c");
if (empty($action) || in_array($action, $options) ) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't simplify this code because you may gain some kind of readability but you would also increase computation time. And that's a thing I would prefer to improve more than readability (code is executed a lot more often than read in plain text).

Why is that?

An expression like yours consisting only of `or` conjunctions will end right the moment the first 'true' value is found. So in best case PHP will just evaluate `empty($action)` with `true` and leave the if-header without evaluating all the other parts. In worst case it will check every part till the end. So in average - without further knowlege about the data you will check - you are running and computing half of the if-header.

But if you use something like `in_array($action, array('a', 'b', 'c'))` than you will construct the whole array with all elements and search in it. So your PHP interpreter has to create all the elements and the array just to match one of the first ones. Which is anyway more computation than your current line.

So think twice about readabilty vs. code complexity.

Comment: I definitely disagree here, especially given the *slight* performance difference involved. Programmer time is much more expensive than hardware. An extra function call here or there won't make a difference unless you're talking about the Google home page.

Comment: I definitely disagree with you, too. In times were we move from stationary hardware to mobile devices we have to think about memory and processing time again like they did in the 80ies where there was no processing time as much as you wantet. Of cause a PHP script won't run on an iOS or Android device, but the general statement that this slight performance difference can be ignored is just wrong. It's essential to always have the complexity and memory-footprints in mind and in case he is ahonorSTUDENT he should be adviced to learn it right from start and not be spoiled with fancy funktions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($action) || preg_match('/^[abc]$/', $action)) { ... }
```

**Edit:** `empty($action)` is needed to allow `false`, `array()`, `0`, and `null` to pass which you may not want.